# Javascript to cycle through each google sheet tab and copy and paste all cells as values only

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I'm completely new to Javascript, so thanks in advance for the help with this as it'll significantly help get me into JS.

What's needed:

- Cycle through each tab in a googlesheet (gsheet) (some tabs may be hidden)
- Copy/Paste all cells as values only

Basically, get rid of all the formulas.  I use a lot of importrange data that is constantly updated.  At the end of closing the books, we need all that import stuff to stop and the tabs to be static.

Comment: You may need something like this  but I do not expect anyone to actually write you the code - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

Comment: I started there already and got lost :(  Thanks though

Comment: Maybe just the code to Cycle through the tabs would help get me started...

Answer (score 0):

Someone on a [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/YHD9C6UuSx0;context-place=forum/docs) sent the answer.  Thanks all.

```
function removeFormulas() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
        .forEach(function (sh) {
            sh.getDataRange().setValues(sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues())
        })
}
```